# How to create a POST Rest API to change a boolean value?

Tags: c#, rest, post

I have the property `ShowInList` in my `CompanyActivity` entity; I wish to make a Rest API to change the boolean value.

I'm developing a project with the backend in C# and SQL while the frontend is in Typescript, but I'm not so expert in C# so I'm trying to understand along the road.

It should be something similar, this is the GET call for the activities:

```
[HttpGet, Route("/api/[controller]/GetActivitiesByCompany/{fk_company?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetActivitiesByCompany([FromRoute] int? fk_company)
    {
        List<Activity> activities = _activityService.GetActivitiesByCompany(fk_company);
        List<ActivityDTO> dto = _autoMappingService.CurrentMapper.Map<List<ActivityDTO>>(activities);
        dto = dto.OrderBy(a => a.CustomerType).ToList();
        return Ok(dto);
    }
```

I'm looking for a call that can change the boolean value of `CompanyActivity.ShowInList` each time I use it.

> Click: status true,
> Click again: status false

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem, but you can trigger your boolean state with

```cs
CompanyActivity.ShowInList = !CompanyActivity.ShowInList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already familiar with using `Get` to receive data from an API.

Now that you want to manipulate entities using a REST API, you'll want something like a `Post` or a `Put`.

In this case, `Post` is maybe the closest to what you're after. `Put` is another option, but would require your TypeScript client to send all the Activity entities (which doesn't feel right). Whereas you *could* maybe to use Post as a way of posting an instruction - in this case, toggling.

Caveats:

- It would be better if you could explain more your use-case, because it feels like there's a better approach.
- Posting a "toggle" feels a bit like executing a command, which isn't really in keeping with a REST philosophy, so it's a bit ugly.

With those caveats in mind, here's a `Post` example that follows your pattern:

```cs
    [HttpPost, Route("/api/[controller]/ActivitiesByCompany/{fk_company?}/shown-in-list/toggles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostToggleActivitiesByCompany([FromRoute] int? fk_company)
    {
        List<Activity> activities = _activityService.GetActivitiesByCompany(fk_company);

        // Toggle values.
        foreach (Activity activity in activities)
        {
            activity.ShowInList = !activity.ShowInList;
        }

        // Store back in your datastore.
        // (this is a guess - you didn't give any details)
        _activityService.PutActivitiesByCompany(fk_company, activities);

        // Return the DTOs, like you do for the Get
        // (again, assuming this is what you want)
        List<ActivityDTO> dto = _autoMappingService.CurrentMapper.Map<List<ActivityDTO>>(activities);
        dto = dto.OrderBy(a => a.CustomerType).ToList();
        return Ok(dto);
    }
```

Comment: Why not HttpPatch?

Comment: Matter of opinion I guess. I'd view Patch as something where you're directly modifying the entity, so the caller would send all N entities (albeit just their IDs and bool props) with and have to compute and specify the toggled bool state for each one. At least, in a Rest sense. Whereas a post without any body suggests more it's an instruction (which is not Restful, as I said) for the API backend to flip the bool on everything in the collection. Like I said - I still don't like it! It's just the closest to what the OP wanted?

Comment: Sorry I'll try again more clearly. With Patch, you pass the entity(s) and their amended state, because you're physically setting entity properties. In OP's use case, this means the client app would take responsibility for determining the right bool state and sending all those entities to the API. Whereas I think OP implies the _backend_ should do the toggle itself, without the client having to worry whether each entity is true/false. This means Patch wouldn't suit it, because the client doesn't know the destination states. So, the closest approx is "Post a Toggle request to that collection".